# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...mockAchievements.map...')

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create an individual switch for each item in the list, each item has an isEnabled that by default it has which is false, and I just want to leave it true when I click on the react native switch, but I'm getting this error whenever I try to activate or disable this switch

```
import {Switch} from "react-native";

const [mockAchievements, setAchievements] = useState([
    {
      isEnabled: false,
    },
    {
      isEnabled: false,
     
    }]
```

```
  function toggleSwitch(value, index) {
    setAchievements((prevAchievements) => {
      return {
        ...prevAchievements,
        [index]: {
          ...prevAchievements[index],
          isEnabled: value,
        },
      };
    });
  }
```

```
    <Switch
     trackColor={{ false: "#E9E9E9", true: "#EEF8FC" }}
     thumbColor={item.isEnabled ? "#006993" : "#CBCBCB"}
     ios_backgroundColor="#CBCBCB"
     onValueChange={(value) => {
     toggleSwitch(value, index);
     }}
                     
     value={item.isEnabled}
     />
```

Comment: You are using `onValueChange={(value) => {
     toggleSwitch(value, index);
     }}` but `index` is nowhere defined in the code snippets, which are available to me. What kind of value does it have? If it is not assigned, this could very well be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function instead

```html
function toggleSwitch(value, index) {
  let dat = [...mockAchievements];
  dat[index].isEnabled = value;
  setAchievements(dat)
}
```

and if I am not wrong, your function returns the state as an object instead of an array

Comment: It's working but it's only loading from the moment it saves and renders the screen,how can i solve this problem?

Comment: In order to not cause any weird behavior by modifying the state directly, `mockAchievements` should be destructured here, like this `let dat = [...mockAchievements]`